# Does it matter if an enemy is attacking me from behind?

Tags: might-and-magic-x-legacy

The first time I saw multiple enemies and one got behind me, a party member yelled "They're flanking us!". Now, when I see multiple enemies I usually try to back up until I have my back against a wall so none can get behind me.

Does this even matter, though? Do enemies get bonuses for attacking from the side or the rear, or is it all just the same as if they're in front of you?